# Separated pgAdmin and cmd psql databases

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

How can I make cmd psql and pgAdmin 4 database sync? because they don't sync. cmd psql outputs postgres, template 01, and template 02 as db, while my pgAdmin4 outputs postgres and SampleDB as my databases.

psql output:

[image]

pgAdmin display:

[image]

pgAdmin inet:

[image]

cmd inet
[cmd inet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaArX.png)

Comment: If you see different data in pgAdmin and psql then you are connecting to two different databases (or even servers). Or if you did changes in one tool but they don't show up in the other tool, then maybe you simply forgot to `commit` them?

Comment: when I create database in both medium, they don't reflect in each other, they separate. lol. Idk if you understand that. check question, I uploaded images. Thanks

Comment: Please show us the output of  `select inet_server_addr()` run from inside `psql` and run from within pgAdmin.

Comment: sorry but how to run it in psql? it says error here.

Comment: You just run `select inet_server_addr();` https://i.imgur.com/9C22HF7.png

Comment: updated. sorry for late reply

Comment: They both run on the same server 1. please help, I want to manipulate my database in pgAdmin because of it's UI.

Comment: Any answers now? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the issue you are facing and what are you trying to achieve. do you want to do psql command and not in the gui PgAdmin4 where you can do more easily?

Here i am make new 3 database from pgAdmin4 and psql command

1. **From PgAdmin4 gui and the database name warehouses**

[image]

2. **From psql command doing with owner name warehoused1**

[image]

And as you can see in pic 2 the result it show the database too

3. **From psql command just create database without owner (default) name warehoused2**

[image]

And see the result? no problem at all. Now see in PgAdmin4

[image]

It shows too in PgAdmin4. I can't give the solution because i don't know the issue you are facing.

Edit : The reason you have different result in your psql and pgAdmin because you have 2 postgresql in your system and your path lead to other postgresql it means your psql connect to different server.

Comment: Thanks for noticing my question! My problem is that my pgAdmin and my psql don't sycn with each other. When I create a database in pgAdmin4 it doesn't reflect in my psql cmd line. and vice versa. they are separated. I want it to be like your. to sync data with each other. How can I fix it to do that? because mine are separated after installation. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you have 2 postgres in your server?

Comment: I don't know about that. how to check?

Comment: What os your server using? if windows check program files and find postgresql installation there

Comment: See the path in environment variables in properties computer. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm and after that see in path system variable and find path postgresql. is the path postgresql refer to your installation. the path postgresql should be like `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help. tho I notice 2 postgreSQL in my C drive, one in C:\PostgreSQL and the other in C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL. can't delete cuz it says in use. will try uninstalling it.

Comment: That's the reason.. You can do psql command in cmd because you using path. if your path refer to other postgresql your using then that is your problem. like  a_horse_with_no_name said. you connect to different server.

Comment: and don't ever do delete on program you are using. if you want to remove just uninstall. if you just delete that's the worse way!

Comment: Solve. unsintalled both and install only one and restarted computer. deleted appData/roaming/pgAdmin and postgreSQL folder. pls post an answer so I can Check. thanks! I'm so happy problem is solved. took days xD

Comment: Please mark my answer so people know your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Turns out I have 2 postgreSQL installed.

Uninstalled both and install only one and restarted computer. deleted appData/roaming/pgAdmin and postgreSQL folder.