# how to sync databases between PSQL and pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

please refer to this post.
[Separated pgAdmin and cmd psql databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381836/separated-pgadmin-and-cmd-psql-databases/52382307)

it hasn't been answered yet. Please help postgres users.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Separated pgAdmin and cmd psql databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381836/separated-pgadmin-and-cmd-psql-databases)

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate. I'm just asking again because it hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: Re-posting a question pointing to a question will not get it more attention. If you want to get answers, take the time to edit it so that it's easy to read, and people know what you're asking.

Comment: I think my question is clear enough. is there any part of it that you don't understand? I'm really confused. I recommend mySQL because of this problem unless resolve. but company wants to use postgres. IDK how to make psql and pgAdmin sync in data.